# Django / MacOS revised efficient development workflow

Tags: python, django, macos, workflow, methodology

I've been now happily developing applications (Django in particular) on the Mac for a few years now.  As part of this process I am always looking to gain efficiencies in my workflow and enjoy reading about other development expieriences.  Now it's my turn to give back.  This is a revision to [my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313737/django-mac-osx-workflow-questions-on-efficient-development-methodologies) with time and expierience under my belt.

**Tools of the trade**

- A Mac Loaded up with [XCode](http://developer.apple.com/xcode/)
- A good set of gnu tools ([coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/), [findutils](http://www.gnu.org/s/findutils/), [diffutils](http://www.gnu.org/s/diffutils/)...)
- A solid set of SCM's [git](https://github.com/), [mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/), [perforce](http://perforce.com), svn (if needed..)
- [iTerm2](http://www.iterm2.com/) - This simply is awesome.
- [ActivePython](http://www.activestate.com/activepython) - The free version → with easy_install, pip, distribute, ipython, pylint available to all.
- [Komodo](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-ide) - (Yes I paid for this) Have tried textmate, eclipse, pycharm, Komodo simply has most everything I need.
- [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/home) (sharing) / [Omnigraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnigraffle/) (mockups) /  [Omnifocus](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnifocus/) (planning)

[image: My Environment]

**The structure**

```
~/Users/<username>  
    /Dropbox/Projects/<project_name>
        /Documents (Personal Documents relating to the project)
        /Public    (Public Documents shared with customer)
    /Projects/<project_name>
        /Documents ../Dropbox/Projects/<project_name>/Documents
        /Public    ../Dropbox/Projects/<project_name>/Public
        /Development
            <virtual_env>
```

**Starting Out**

Create a virtual env and get it activated.

```
$ cd ~/Users/<username>/Projects/<project_name>/Development
$ virtualenv --no-site-packages --distribute <project>_django
$ cd <project>_django; . ./bin/activate
$ echo "alias <project>d="cd ~/Projects/<project_name>/Development/<project_django/www/; . ../bin/activate" > ~/.bash_profile
```

Get core modules installed and start a django project.

```
$ pip install django django-debug-toolbar dbgp
$ django-admin.py startproject www
$ pip freeze > www/requirements.txt
```

Go forth and develop.

```
$ cd www
$ django-admin.py startapp core
```

**Comments**

1. Everything under `www` (ignoring .pyc's) is stored in your SCM.
2. Create your Komodo project inside the www tree and ensure that you add the `../lib/python2.7/site-packages/` tree to your project.
3. In Komodo I created several macros which really help me out

   - Debug session runs `./manage.py runserver` under pydb which allows good introspection and awesome debugging capability all from within Komodo (as shown above).  This is also available in PyDev.  If interested I can share this.  It requires #2 for scalability.
   - Pylint - Run pylint on your code and ensure at least 8.75 score.
   - Tab Titles - Shamelessly swiped and tweaked from [here](http://community.activestate.com/forum-topic/tab-title-restriction-hurts-komodos-usability-django-projects)
4. I use iTerm for `./manage.py shell_plus` - This is way superior than the Komodo built in interpreter.

**Thoughts??**

Please share your views and point out areas for improvement.  I'm always searching for better ways of doing things...

Comment: This is very cool, but it's not really a question for SO. Maybe you should post it on a blog...

Comment: Have a look at virtualenvwrapper.

Comment: Hey Daniel - You are correct - but I feel this it is german to SO as most of the community could benefit from my pains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Daniel pointed out this isn't a question per se.  So there isn't an answer - other than sure..